# How can I check whether my RDD or dataframe is cached or not?

Tags: apache-spark

I have created a dataframe say df1. I cached this by using df1.cache(). How can I check whether this has been cached or not? 
Also is there a way so that I am able to see all my cached RDD's or dataframes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can call `getStorageLevel.useMemory` on the Dataframe and the RDD to find out if the dataset is in memory.

For the Dataframe do this:

```
scala> val df = Seq(1, 2).toDF()
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: int]

scala> df.storageLevel.useMemory
res1: Boolean = false

scala> df.cache()
res0: df.type = [value: int]

scala> df.storageLevel.useMemory
res1: Boolean = true
```

For the RDD do this:

```
scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(1,2))
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[1] at parallelize at <console>:21

scala> rdd.getStorageLevel.useMemory
res9: Boolean = false

scala> rdd.cache()
res10: rdd.type = ParallelCollectionRDD[1] at parallelize at <console>:21

scala> rdd.getStorageLevel.useMemory
res11: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a similar function in python?

Comment: I think so, check the Python APIs to be sure.

Comment: I cannot seem to find it, if you have any idea as to where it might me, please help me out

Comment: Would this flag (the storage level) be reset to NONE if the cached RDD is overwritten e.g. by another RDD's cache function call and too less memory to cache both?

Comment: This doesn't tell you if the RDD is in memory or not. This just says whether the RDD is a *candidate* to be cached in memory.

Answer (score 11):

@Arnab, 
Did you find the function in Python? 
Here is an example for DataFrame DF:

> ```
> DF.cache()
> print DF.is_cached
> ```

Hope this helps. 
Ram

Comment: An example of what? There is no such method in DataFrame class.

Comment: is_cached is not a method, it's an attribute of the DataFrame class.

Answer (score 8):

Starting since Spark (Scala) 2.1.0, this can be checked for a dataframe as follows:

```
dataframe.storageLevel.useMemory
```

Answer (score 4):

In Java and Scala, following method could used to find all the persisted RDDs:
`sparkContext.getPersistentRDDs()`
[Here is link to documentation.](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#getPersistentRDDs())`

Looks like this method is not available in python yet:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2141

But one could use this short-term hack:

```
sparkContext._jsc.getPersistentRDDs().items()
```

Comment: "Returns an immutable map of RDDs that have marked themselves as persistent via cache() call. Note that this does not necessarily mean the caching or computation was successful." -- this does not appear different than checking `storageLevel` since it does not verify whether or not it is currently cached.

Answer (score 4):

You can retrieve the storage level of a `RDD` since [Spark 1.4](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/storage/StorageLevel.html) and since [Spark 2.1](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#storageLevel()) for `DataFrame`.

```
val storageLevel = rdd.getStorageLevel
val storageLevel = dataframe.storageLevel
```

Then you can check where it's stored as follows:

```
val isCached: Boolean = storageLevel.useMemory || storageLevel.useDisk || storageLevel.useOffHeap
```

Answer (score 0):

The only sensible answer I've found is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63037191/1524650

However, this uses an `SparkSession.sharedState` which is marked as "Unstable":

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.html#sharedState:org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState

It would seem that there's no good way to do this, then. You can check that Spark has been instructed to try to cache something, but there is no public API to check which objects are currently in cache.